# how to check a substring in an IF htaccess statement

Tags: .htaccess, substring

I'm trying to find a way to filter on a substring in htaccess but cannot find any clues :-(

In this example I need to avoid redirection on the development server:
example.lan

while all the other domains, i.e. example.com will need to be redirected.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.lan'">
    #
    # LOCAL DEVELOPMENT SERVER
    #
</If>
<Else>
    #
    # PRODUCTION SERVER
    #
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</Else>
```

How do I perform a substring search?

Thank you!

I searched on google but cannot find an answer :-(

Comment: And what substring search are you taking about?

Comment: Why can't you use a normal `RewriteCond` to check the http host name?

Comment: The documentation has a few examples that demonstrate using regular expressions for example: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if   Why is that not suitable for you?

Comment: I need to check if %{HTTP_HOST} ends with ".lan" I do something and if it ends with ".com" I do something else :-)

Comment: `<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /\.lan$/">` should do the trick. `=~` to enable regex, `/` around the regex as delimiters, dot escaped via a backslash, and `$` to anchor the pattern at the end.

Comment: @CBroe Why not put that in an "answer" and get the question out of the unanswered question queue?

Comment: However, this seems like an XY problem. For the limited(?) example in the question, you shouldn't be using an `<If>` expression to begin with (as arkascha mentioned above). Generally, you want to avoid using mod_rewrite directives inside an `<If/Else>` expression since they are merged very late (after the request has been mapped back to the filesystem) so behave quite differently. If you are wanting to have different rule blocks for local development and production when consider using an `<IfDefine>` instead, which is better suited to this.